# Combine Access queries and convert to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access-2010

I have three tables.

- tkDetail
- LD
- EM (only used to pull a first and last name)

I queried the 1st table as such in MS Access:

```
SELECT 
    dbo_tkDetail.WBS1, dbo_tkDetail.LaborCode, dbo_tkDetail.TransDate, 
    [LastName]+','+' '+[FirstName] AS Name, dbo_tkDetail.RegHrs, 
    dbo_tkDetail.OvtHrs, dbo_tkDetail.BillExt
FROM 
    dbo_tkDetail 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo_EM ON dbo_tkDetail.Employee = dbo_EM.Employee
WHERE 
    (((dbo_tkDetail.WBS1) Not Like '9%' And (dbo_tkDetail.WBS1) Not Like 'I%'));
```

I queried the second as such:

```
SELECT 
    dbo_LD.WBS1, dbo_LD.LaborCode, dbo_LD.Employee, dbo_LD.TransDate, 
    dbo_LD.Name, dbo_LD.RegHrs, dbo_LD.OvtHrs, dbo_LD.BillExt
FROM 
    dbo_LD;
```

Then I queried the queries as such:

```
SELECT 
    [Time Keeper Detail].WBS1, [Time Keeper Detail].LaborCode, 
    [Time Keeper Detail].TransDate, [Time Keeper Detail].Name, 
    [Time Keeper Detail].RegHrs, [Time Keeper Detail].OvtHrs, 
    [Time Keeper Detail].BillExt
FROM 
    [Time Keeper Detail] 
LEFT JOIN 
    [Labor Detail] ON ([Time Keeper Detail].[Name] = [Labor Detail].[Name])   
                   AND ([Time Keeper Detail].TransDate = [Labor Detail].TransDate)
WHERE 
    ((([Labor Detail].Name) Is Null));
```

This was the only way I could achieve the result set that i needed.

now i need to combine these three queries into one and convert to SQL server to run it from a data modeler. I am stuck.

Comment: I would urge you to read what you posted and ask yourself if you think you would be able to answer this based only on the information posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a complete guess, but I think what you're after is this (I don't really know what you mean by "query the query", but I am hazarding a guess):

```
SELECT D.WBS1,
       D.LaborCode,
       D.TransDate, 
       EM.[LastName]+','+' '+ EM.[FirstName] AS [Name], --Guessed the object these come from here
       D.RegHrs, 
       D.OvtHrs,
       D.BillExt
FROM dbo_tkDetail D
     INNER JOIN dbo_EM EM ON D.Employee = EM.Employee
     LEFT JOIN  dbo_LD LD ON E.[LastName]+','+' '+ E.[FirstName] = LD.[name]
                         AND D.TransDate = LD.TransDate
WHERE D.WBS1 NOT LIKE '9%'
  AND D.WBS1 NOT LIKE 'I%'
  AND LD.[Name] IS NULL;
```

Comment: It's giving me a syntax error msg. Trying to work that out

Comment: A syntax error..? *Why do users say they get an error and not post the error still?* It might be that I'd put 2 of the alias as `E`, rather than `EM`; but I'm still playing the guessing game here.

Comment: Accepting my answer as a solution would be nice then, @user3740736  . ;)